# Is there some database or software to look for patterns in polynomials?

Tags: sequences-and-series, polynomials, computational-mathematics, computer-algebra-systems

Like if I am looking at these polynomials,

$$x^8-8x^6+20x^4-16x^2+3$$

$$x^{10}-12x^8+48x^6-72x^4+33x^2$$

$$x^{12}-16x^{10}+88x^8-192x^6+138x^4$$

And I want to know if they are members of some known sequence or not..

How can I go about it?

Comment: there's always the [Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](http://www.oeis.org).

Comment: But how does that help with polynomial sequences?

Comment: This site might be able to help if you tell us where those polynomials come from/how to generate more. Three data points isn't exactly enough to fill the absence of meaning behind them.

Comment: I am not sure that is easy to explain - these come from certain spectrum calculation on graphs - but its very off the standard things - the first one corresponds to K22, the next one is K23 and last one from K24 and so on...

Comment: I'm fairly certain that the next polynomial starts with $x^{14}-20x^{12}$. The next term [might](http://oeis.org/A033579) or might not be $140x^{10}$.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever played around with [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com)?

Lots of super useful math tools. Try putting `x^8−8x^6+20x^4−16x^2+3 vs x^10−12x^8+48x^6−72x^4+33x^2` in the prompt, for example.