# Reference (database) for polynomials

Tags: polynomials

> Suppose I want to know what is known about the following polynomial 
>   $$x^4 - 2x^2y^2 - 2x^2z^2 + y^4 - 2y^2z^2 + z^4.$$

Where can one find such information?

Comment: What kind of information do you want?

Comment: i have found this here https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi2rca18NPVAhWKtxQKHc2hDHUQFgg4MAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fhomepages.math.uic.edu%2F~jan%2Fdemo.html&usg=AFQjCNGOCkN6hDVox34zWaIJBdPKlyHYdQ

Comment: @ajotatxe: for example, maximal number of facets in chambers of complement of corresponding hyperplane arrangement. But this example suits only restricted set of polynomials, so corresponding information should be different for each polynomial, of course.

Comment: @Dr. Sonnhard Graubner: It is too specialized

Comment: Related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1148371/is-there-some-database-or-software-to-look-for-patterns-in-polynomials. It for some reason wasn't shown while I typed mine.

Answer (score 1):

It's just
$$(x+y+z)(x-y-z)(x+y-z)(x-y+z).$$
We can get it by the following way.
$$x^4+y^4+z^4-2x^2y^2-2x^2z^2-2y^2z^2=$$
$$=x^4+y^4+z^4-2x^2y^2-2x^2z^2+2y^2z^2-4y^2z^2=$$
$$=(x^2-y^2-z^2)^2-(2yz)^2=$$
$$=(x^2-y^2-z^2-2yz)(x^2-y^2-z^2+2yz)=$$
$$=(x^2-(y+z)^2)(x^2-(y-z)^2),$$
which gives the final factorization.

Also, the area of a triangle with sides-lengths $x$, $y$ and $z$ it's
$$\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{2x^2y^2+2x^2z^2+2y^2z^2-x^4-y^4-z^4}$$